# Golang unmarshal JSON response, then convert the field name into snake_case

Tags: json, go, struct, unmarshalling, snakecasing

I want to get data with json tag whose source has PascalCase format and save it to my database. But before going into the database, I want to change the PascalCase format to snake_case format.

My question seems to be the opposite of this question ([Golang Unmarshal an JSON response, then marshal with Struct field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63248152/golang-unmarshal-an-json-response-then-marshal-with-struct-field-names)). But instead of having PascalCase, I want to have snake_case in the name field

Here is the sample code that i wrote:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)

// models data to save in DB
type (
    Person struct {
        FirstName string      `json:"FirstName"`
        LastName  string      `json:"LastName"`
        Children  []ChildData `json:"Children,omitempty"`
    }
    ChildData struct {
        ChildName string `json:"ChildName"`
        Age       int    `json:"Age"`
        FavColor  string `json:"FavColor"`
    }
    PersonOut struct {
        FirstName string      `json:"first_name"`
        LastName  string      `json:"last_name"`
        Children  []ChildData `json:"children,omitempty"`
    }
    ChildDataOut struct {
        ChildName string `json:"child_name"`
        Age       int    `json:"age"`
        FavColor  string `json:"fav_Color"`
    }
)

// grisha is data from fetch API
var grisha = map[string]interface{}{
    "FirstName": "Grisha",
    "LastName":  "Jeager",
    "Children": []map[string]interface{}{
        {
            "ChildName": "Zeke",
            "Age":       2,
            "FavColor":  "blue",
        }, {
            "ChildName": "Eren",
            "Age":       3,
            "FavColor":  "red",
        },
    },
}

func getJsonfromAPI(data map[string]interface{}) []byte {
    grishaJson, _ := json.MarshalIndent(grisha, "", "    ")
    return grishaJson
}

func parsingJSON(jsonInput []byte) {
    var person Person
    json.Unmarshal(jsonInput, &person)

    out := PersonOut(person)
    payload2, err := json.MarshalIndent(out, "", "    ")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Println(string(payload2))
}

func main() {
    data := getJsonfromAPI(grisha)
    parsingJSON(data)
}
```

The result that I want is like

```
 {
    "first_name": "Grisha",
    "last_name": "Jeager",
    "children": [
        {
            "child_name": "Zeke",
            "age": 2,
            "fav_color": "blue"
        },
        {
            "child_name": "Eren",
            "age": 3,
            "fav_color": "red"
        }
    ]
}
```

but the result is still having PascalCase in the nested field:

```
 {
    "first_name": "Grisha",
    "last_name": "Jeager",
    "children": [
        {
            "ChildName": "Zeke",
            "Age": 2,
            "FavColor": "blue"
        },
        {
            "ChildName": "Eren",
            "Age": 3,
            "FavColor": "red"
        }
    ]
}
```

I was wondering how to convert field name for the nested structure from unmarshal JSON.

Comment: "the program does not work." is not a very helpful problem description. Can you be more specific?

Comment: it cannot accept nested data and cannot be run. but when I commented out the nested field struct, the program works and returned snake_case field format. 
the result that i want is the field output will be snake_case including the nested data structure.

Comment: "it cannot accept nested data and cannot be run" is still not a valid problem description.

Comment: thanks for your comment, i edited and added some examples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting one struct to another works **only** if their their underlying types (ignoring tags) are identical. If the underlying types are not identical you cannot do the conversion.

Take for example the structs `S1` and `S2`, in the following snippet their *underlying types* are identical and you can convert one to the other:

```golang
type S1 struct {
    Field T1
}
type S2 struct {
    Field T1
}
type T1 string

_ = S2(S1{}) // ok
```

However, in the next snippet their *underlying types* are NOT identical and therefore you cannot convert one to the other:

```golang
type S1 struct {
    Field T1
}
type S2 struct {
    Field T2
}
type T1 string
type T2 string

_ = S2(S1{}) // cannot convert S1{} (value of type S1) to type S2
```

For more details read the spec on conversions here: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions

---

So to convert between two struct whose *underlying types* are NOT identical you have to manually do the conversion field by field. However, in the case of JSON marshaling, you can make this a bit nicer by implementing the `json.Marshaler` interface and have the individual instances "convert themselves".

```golang
type Person struct {
    FirstName string      `json:"FirstName"`
    LastName  string      `json:"LastName"`
    Children  []ChildData `json:"Children"`
}

func (p Person) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type T struct {
        FirstName string      `json:"first_name"`
        LastName  string      `json:"last_name"`
        Children  []ChildData `json:"children"`
    }

    return json.Marshal(T(p))
}

type ChildData struct {
    ChildName string `json:"ChildName"`
    Age       int    `json:"Age"`
    FavColor  string `json:"FavColor"`
}

func (d ChildData) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type T struct {
        ChildName string `json:"child_name"`
        Age       int    `json:"age"`
        FavColor  string `json:"fav_color"`
    }

    return json.Marshal(T(d))
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/UGJY5p490Gs

Answer (score 0):

https://go.dev/play/p/l4O8KBNrm1T

We need to:

1. Mapping Person to PersonOut
2. Mapping ChildData to ChildDataOut

```golang
func childDataToChildDataOut(childData ChildData) ChildDataOut {
    return ChildDataOut{
        ChildName: childData.ChildName,
        Age:       childData.Age,
        FavColor:  childData.FavColor,
    }
}

func personToPersonOut(person Person) PersonOut {
    var children []ChildDataOut

    for _, childData := range person.Children {
        childDataOut := childDataToChildDataOut(childData)
        children = append(children, childDataOut)
    }

    return PersonOut{
        FirstName: person.FirstName,
        LastName:  person.LastName,
        Children:  children,
    }
}
```